# XML ancestors wanted

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C#, I need to get

```
currentnode.parentnode.parentnode.parentnode.firstchild.lastchild.lastchild
```

I am using to generating MLM tree some of the label which represent individual node overload at the fourth level so I was trying to get that nodes and separate them.

I am new to XML, I hope my question is clear.

Comment: "Xml is like violence: if its not working, you're obviously not using enough of it." And by that, I mean that you should not use XML as a concrete data structure. Take 10 minutes and write some code to map your nodes to a real, type-safe hierarchy; you'll save yourself a nightmare of effort in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the current node you want to work on, then XmlNode defines a ParentNode FirstChild, and LastNode property that you can use to do this [see](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode_members(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using XQuery or XPath in order to perform queries on your XML tree. 
There's a nice tutorial [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/myXPath.aspx), showing all the common options.